# A function $ f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ strictly increasing is continous in [a,b]?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to do the exercise number 5 of section 2.6 of the book: A user friendly introduction to lebesgue measure and integration by Gail S. Nelson it is on page 103 and says: Suppose $ f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}  $ is a strictly increasing function. Prove that $f$ is a measurable function.

At the beginning I though that $f$ must be continuous in $[a,b]$. But instead
I divided  my reasoning by cases: if $\alpha < f(a) $ so $f$ is measurable because $ \{x\in [a,b]: \alpha < f(x)\} $ is $[a,b]$ that is measurable. Now if $f(a)\le \alpha < f(b) $ then $ \{x\in [a,b]: \alpha < f(x)\} $ is $ (f^{-1}(\alpha),b] $ that is also measurable. Finally if $ f(b) \le\alpha $ then $ \{x\in [a,b]: \alpha < f(x)\} $ is $\emptyset$ that is measurable.

Is that correct?

Comment: You need to explain $f^{-1}$. But basically it is correct.

Comment: is the pre-image of the number $\alpha$ under $f$

Comment: $f$ need not to be continuous. So there might be no pre image to $\alpha$.

Comment: but if $f$ is defined on the interval $[a,b]$ it means that for every $x \in [a,b]$ there exists $f(x)$ isn't?  and since  in that case $f(a)\le \alpha <f(b) $  there must be an element such that $f(x_{\alpha}) = \alpha$

Comment: nope. $f([a,b])$ isn't necessarily $[f(a), f(b)]$.

Comment: If $f$ is strictly increasing then $ f(a) <f(x)< f(b) $ for all $x \in [a,b]$ thus $f([a,b]) $ is $[f(a),f(b)]$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91281/discussion-between-jose-marin-and-user251257).

Comment: consider $f$ on $[0,1]$ defined by $f(x) = x$ for $x< 1$ and $f(1) = 3$. Obviously, $\alpha = 2$ doesn't have a pre-image.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that a strictly increasing function is continuous, however it *is* true that an increasing function is continuous almost everywhere (in fact, the set of discontinuity points must be countable). For instance, consider the function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
f(x) := \begin{cases}
x & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2},\\
2x & \text{if } \frac{1}{2} < x \leq 1.
\end{cases}
$$

As for the measurability of an increasing function, the proof you've given could be written in a more formal manner. To establish measurability, it will be enough to show that the set $$\{x \in [a,b] : f(x) > \alpha\}$$ is measurable for each $\alpha  \in \mathbb{R}$.

To this end, we fix $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $$E_\alpha := \{ x \in [a,b] : f(x) > \alpha\}.$$ If $E_\alpha = \emptyset$, there is nothing to show and we are done. Otherwise, by setting $s := \inf{E_\alpha}$ we find that $E_\alpha$ is an interval. Indeed, we have either $E_\alpha = (s,b]$ or $ E_\alpha = [s,b]$. In any case, $E_\alpha$ is measurable.

---

**Edit**: As requested, let's check that $E_\alpha$ must indeed be an interval.  By definition of $s$, we must have $f(s) \geq \alpha$. Hence, there are exactly two possibilities:

- Case $f(s) = \alpha$. In this case, we claim that $E_\alpha = (s,b]$. First, let $x \in E_\alpha$ so that $f(x) > \alpha = f(s)$. Since $f$ is increasing, we must have $x > s$ whence $x \in (s,b]$. That is, $E_\alpha \subseteq (s,b]$. Conversely, let $x \in (s,b]$ be given. Because $f$ is increasing, we see that $f(x) \geq f(s) = \alpha$. If $f(x) = \alpha$, then $x$ would be a lower-bound for $E_\alpha$ strictly larger than $s$ -- a contradiction. It follows that $f(x) > \alpha$, i.e. $(s,b] \subseteq E_\alpha$. To summarize, we have $E_\alpha = (s,b]$.
- Case $f(s) > \alpha$ so that, especially, $s \in E_\alpha$. Because $f$ is increasing, we have that $[s,b] \subseteq E_\alpha$. Conversely, for every $x \in E_\alpha$, the definition of $s$ tells us that $x \geq s$. Hence, $E_\alpha \subseteq [s,b]$. To summarize, $E_\alpha = [s,b]$.

So, in either case, $E_\alpha$ is an interval (and thus measurable).

Comment: Thank you for the example! Now I see why I couldn't prove that strictly increasing implies continuity. In the other hand, I don't understand your proof. what is ${f>\alpha} $.  And how do you know that $\E_{alpha} is an interval?

Comment: $\{f > \alpha\}$ is the pre-image of $(\alpha,\infty)$. I've edited my post to clarify this. I will also clarify why $E_\alpha$ must be an interval.